# What language the AI demo from Mark Zukerberg is written in?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

Those few lines of code are from Marks Zuckerberg's  new AI. I tried few wild guesses but nothing seems to answer my question :/

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not Facebook customer service. Also, it shows absolutely zero research effort. Finally, images of code are absolutely useless and don't count as including the code at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's [the Hack programming language](http://hacklang.org/) developed at Facebook for their [HHVM platform](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm)—a JIT and a VM to run PHP and Hack.

Comment: The anser is courtesy of `evilb1oodydemon` over there at the `dotnet@conference.jabber.ru` XMPP room.